# Stepping through material design wpf treeview with additional TreeViewAssist requires two keystrokes per step

Tags: wpf, treeview, material-design

when adding a TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplateSelector item to a wpf material design treeview (http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) I need two keystrokes to get to the next element because it always focusses the additional template.

I did not find any properties that could avoid this behaviour. It even exists in the TreeView demo of the material design package.

Here is the xaml example from the original material design demo which also requires 2 keystrokes to jump to the next element (event when the additional template is disabled).

```xml
<TreeView>
  <materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <materialDesign:ColorZone
        Mode="PrimaryLight"
        CornerRadius="6">
        <TextBlock
          FontSize="10"
          Margin="8 1 8 1"
          FontStyle="Italic">
        8 planets
      </TextBlock>
      </materialDesign:ColorZone>
    </DataTemplate>
  </materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate>
  <TreeViewItem
    Header="Solar System">
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Mercury"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Venus"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Earth"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Mars"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Jupiter"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Saturn"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Uranus"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
    <TreeViewItem
      Header="Neptune"
      materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.AdditionalTemplate="{x:Static materialDesign:TreeViewAssist.SuppressAdditionalTemplate}" />
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

I would be grateful if someone has a way to achieve the desired behavior to only require 1 keystroke to walk through the tree without even focusing the additional template.

Comment: It's not a template it's focussing, it's a control. Either look carefully and work out what it is or spin up Snoop and use the events tab to work out what takes focus.   Or guess - probably that Textblock. Apply Focussable="False" to whatever is taking focus.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried setting Focussable to False of both the colorzone and the textbox but it still took 2 keystrokes. 
I worked around the issue by getting rid of the treeviewassist and changing my template to include a similar field.